# Xamarin.iOS native project error:

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am starting a new Xamarin.iOS project. I am on latest version of Xamarin as of the time of writing this question(4.5 build I believe).
I have a local Mac(El Captain) connected.

The following is my project structure:

[image]

Weirdest thing that happens here is, when I build my project I get the following errors:[image]

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Why I said it is weird is because when I start a new project (Xamarin.Forms PCL: which comes with separate solution for each platform iOS, android and UWP) and then add another new Xamarin.iOS project to this solution and make this newly added Xamarin.iOS project as startup project and when I run the project, I do not get the above error. (You can remove all other Xamarin.Forms project from the solution and just keep the new Xamarin.iOS and it will still work)

For those of you who are facing the issue I mentioned in the above question, this comment is a cheap and quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

To build for iOS, you need Xcode installed on the connected Mac. Your error message calls for Xcode 8.0 or later.

You will also need to sign up for an [Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com) account and connect it to Xcode in the Accounts tab of the Xcode Preferences.

[image]

Comment: Yes Brandon, I have Xcode 8.2.x installed on my Mac. I have even provided the default Xcode path in Visual Studio -> Tools -> Xamarin -> iOS settings.
Still for some reason, I am not able to run native iOS projects but I can run Xamarin.Forms.